# Achievements view loads forever, never showing

Tags: bug, android-app

When opening the achievements view in the android app, it's showing the spinner as if loading, but never finish the loading.

I've waited for this one to go away but it's survived the app being killed as well as a reboot of my phone. I'm posting this question from the Android app now, so the app itself works.

App version 1.0.77

Comment: Reproduced in version 1.0.77, what version you have?

Comment: @Shadow I have 1.0.77.

Comment: Any plans for an update? Currently I'm checking my rep on my profile or looking at questions I've answered.

Comment: @Shadow actually last time there was an enormous horrible error the developer fixed it almost immediately, but I understand time constraints.

Comment: @shadow yeah. Also, I don't know what time zone he/she is in, but here it's not long past the crack of dawn, which is often not a time when people are up.

Comment: Update: it's also [borked for the iOS app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270510/rep-point-changes-arent-showing-in-ios-app-achievements-tab), which means the API itself is broken. I'll delete all my comments here.